# How can we use :before or :after pseudo-element on an input field in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to use the :after CSS pseudo-element on an input field, but it does not working. i tried below code please suggest me how can i use this pseudo-element

```
input[type=text]:after {
  content: '[after]';
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

Search: <input type="text" name="search">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ9FJ29FSTVU

Comment: Dhaval Marthak  i want to archive this using angular

Comment: Whether you use angular or C# or any other web languages, HTML is same for everything. You use forms and this is (input) form element and according to link i've provided you can not apply pseudo selector `::after` to input elements!

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
The css `::after` and `::before` selector render inside a container and  `input` tag cannot contain any child. Hence, both the selector won't work with `input` tag or any other tag that does not support child nodes

So, you cannot achieve it using plain CSS. Please refer to this [link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)

You are using wrong [css after selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp).

This should work

```
input[type=text]::after {
  content: '[after]';
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ9FJ29FSTVU  please check my code here

Comment: thats why i want to use angular

Comment: cant achive this using angular?